# Selecting Features in ArcGIS based on their relation other layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, features, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I am extremely new to GIS mapping and I'm trying to do what I believe would be relatively simple. I have two layers: one contains data on school locations in Chicago and the other contains data on child abductions; both layers are point shape. What I would like is to only show the schools that are within one mile of a child abduction in order to reduce the number of features shown on the map.

I apologize if this is a duplicated question, but the 'Similar Questions' box didn't suggest the type of question I'm looking to have answered.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Technical details: I'm operating on a Windows 7 OS using ArcEditor Single Use evaluation trial software. I'm somewhat familiar with Python (but not overly familiar) if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only show the schools within one mile of a child abduction (creepy!):

Open ArcMap and add both layers, use [Select by location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) to select the schools:
[image]

Then right click on the schools, go down to *selection>* and find *make layer from selected features*, then turn off the school layer.

This selection can be exported if you right click on the layer then go to *Data>* then *export data*.

A selection layer is just a subset, it's not a new shapefile so anything you do to this layer is reflected in the original unless you export it.

Comment: You're welcome. What you *really* want to do is Near http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000 and find the maximum value. Call this layer "where I want to send *my* children to school".